# Kotlin type mismatch with generics

Tags: generics, kotlin, nullable

I recently experienced an issue regarding safe navigation operator (`?.`) and generics.

```
class A<T : Any?>(private var value: T) {
    fun function() {
        value?.let { 
            val notNull: Any = it
            //                 ^^
            // Type mismatch: 
            // Required: Any
            // Found:    T
        }
    }
}
```

I believe the above code should have no problems running but it produces the error shown above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Despite the fact that the block passed to let is only execute if the value is not null, `it` is still of type T inside the block. So you can assign is to a variable of type Any?, but not to a variable of type Any.

Comment: @JBNizet so can I be sure that it's not null and just cast it?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But I don't really understand why your method is generic.

Comment: You could define your class like this instead: `class A<T : Any>(private var value: T?)`

Comment: @marstran didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've left a few things out of your example to get that error. So I'm going to guess and what you are really are trying to achieve and please forgive me if I have misinterpreted your intent.

```
class A<T : Any>(private val value: T?) { // T? instead of T to allow null value
  fun function() {
    value?.let {
      // *it* is already a non-null because you did a ?.let on a T? type
    }
  }
}
```